# MySQL driver module issue with Movable Type

Tags: mysql, perl, macos, cpan, movabletype

I am able to get mt-check to run, but it says that DBD::MySQL module is not installed.  Here is what it says:

```
DBI (version >= 1.21)
Your server has DBI installed (version 1.52).

DBD::mysql
Your server does not have DBD::mysql installed, or DBD::mysql requires another module that is not installed. The DBD::mysql database driver is required to use MySQL Database. Please consult the installation instructions for help in installing DBD::mysql.
```

However, when I run `sudo cpan DBD:mysql` it says that it is up-to-date:

```
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.19)
Going to read /Users/.../.cpan/Metadata
Database was generated on Thu, 01 Jul 2010 04:28:19 GMT
DBD::mysql is up to date (4.014).
```

When I try to run mt.cgi I get an error:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC...
```

When I checked `perl -V` (or `sudo perl -V`) the `@INC` value doesn't include the path that is listed by cpan for being correctly installed.

Is the issue that it is installed for me (user) rather than the system?  Do I need to reinstall the module?  Have you come across this?

If it helps, I am using Mac OS 10.5.5 with MT 4.3.2.I

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the value of `@INC` look different between `sudo perl -V` and `perl -V`? cpan may have installed the module somewhere where you can't see it as non-root.  Also, can you run mt.cgi as root (after ensuring it doesn't perform an `rm -rf`) :) ?

Comment: First, the `@INC` is no different whether I run with sudo or not.  Second, I ran `perl mt.cgi` (after checking ;-) and it gives me the HTML output an error page (but with HTTP status 200):  `Connection error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`  I double-checked my mt-config.cgi and the SQL section is correct.  Thoughts?

Comment: One other note that may be a big deal... the `Going to read /Users/.../.cpan/Metadata` (in the cpan run) is actually the path to my User's .cpan directory (if that is not clear) and that is not in the list of Perl Include Path in mt-check.cgi is showing.  Should I add my user path? Or do I need to do something to install the bundle into one of the default Perl Include Paths?

Comment: I just tried to install this via MacPorts as well, but no luck... help please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting on this old question because getting Movable Type to run on MacOS X has been a challenge for me, and I am in the business of providing technical support for Movable Type.

Successful installation procedures vary by build of MacOS X. This means that the easiest way to get Movable Type running on MacOS X 10.5.5 may not be the easiest for 10.6 (Snow Leopard), 10.7 (Lion), 10.8 (Mountain Lion), etc.  Successful installation procedures differ if you are running MacOS X Server instead of MacOS X, especially prior to Mountain Lion.

In terms of getting MacOS X 10.5.5 to run Movable Type 4.3x, which was the original question, I'd recommend reading and following [Install Movable Type on a Mac](http://www.beausmith.com/mt/2009/05/install-movable-type-on-a-mac.php) written by Beau Smith back in May 2009.  This contains very specific instructions for MacOS X 10.5.5.  I successfully installed Movable Type on that build of MacOS by following these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

try running `sudo cpan force install DBD::mysql`

Comment: Sorry, I got rid of all the Moveable Type stuff and went with Wordpress a while ago. If someone else finds this helpful, I'll definitely mark it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experiences as [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558588/172602), with configs changing by each version of OSX. The latest issue was after upgrading from Mountain Lion to Mavericks (10.9). I got the same error the original user reported. [HaloWebMaster’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869617/172602) was close to what I needed, but my OSX does not have `cpan` as an available Terminal command by default, so I resolved it this way:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
# enter password, then hit enter to accept defaults at all prompts if CPAN needs to set up
cpan[1]> install DBD::mysql
```

This ended with `/usr/bin/make install  -- OK`, and then I typed `exit` to exit CPAN shell.

At this point, I reloaded `mt.cgi` and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe with PERL. I SOLVED this problem using the tutorial - http://codesphpjs.blogspot.com/2015/04/install-movabletype-on-wamp-server.html

installing Strawberry Perl was solution